# Decode cryptic AIX ld 0711-788 error message - fixed-up instruction is not a branch

Tags: ld, aix

I get this cryptic message when linking my code on AIX:

```
ld: 0711-788 SEVERE ERROR: Object /dir/libxx.so, RLD address 0x5106 in section 1:
    The fixed-up instruction at address 0x5104 is not a branch.
    Its opcode is 14.
```

If I'm reading the docs correctly, RLD is a [relocation entry](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds3/ld.htm), but I would definitely appreciate a clarification if I'm incorrect.

A Google search turns up this [particular page](http://mymemory.translated.net/it/English/Italian/rld) but it's just a listing of error messages that's possible within ld.

Comment: libxx.so? That is cryptic! ;-) My **guess** would be that there's an incompatibility of versions of libxx with other libs that are relying on libxx. Assuming you're building  an opensource project, you're best *hope* for help is to find the developers email list and post there. Good luck.

Comment: I guess that's possible. I should check if the arguments I used to compile & link libxx are compatible with my own binary.

However, I did neglect to mention that the same ld command works on one AIX machine but not another.

I was hoping that someone would be able to explain the error message a bit better so that I would have some clues to determining what's different on the non-working machine and the working one.

Comment: there's a very strong community of AIX support at http://ittoolbox.com, but they're also very crabby, and expect a well structured question that shows some effort. You'll want to include the  debug version of running `make` in both systems as well as versions of all tools that are being used. Good luck.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  This usually happens with gcc.  There is some option to prevent it but I wanted to be sure you are using gcc first.

Comment: We use xlC_r but I'm not sure with libxx is compiled with. I'll double check

Answer (score 1):

This error was caused by different AIX versions on the machine.

- libxx.so was compiled on an AIX machine @ 5.3 TL12 SP3.
- Our machine doing the linking had AIX @ 5.3 TL8 SP4

Once we upgraded our machine doing the linking to the latter technical level, everything was fine.

Thanks again for all the suggestions everyone!